# post content of <div> to another page on button click

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have function `showuser()` which post variable `sent` on form submit event.

I am getting few more variable in the same function and want to post it with `sent` but they did not get received on another page.

Here is my code, what is my mistake?

```
function showUser(form, e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.returnValue=false;
      var xmlhttp;
      var sent = form.elements['sent'].value;
      var sent2 = form.elements['sent2'].value;  // sent2 is the name of one of <div> in the form where sent is there. But getting error : "TypeError: form.elements.sent2 is undefined"

      var divElements = document.getElementById('d1').innerHTML;
      var text1 = document.getElementById('previewUrl').innerText || document.getElementById('previewUrl').textContent;
      var text2 = document.getElementById('previewTitle').innerText || document.getElementById('previewTitle').textContent;
      var text3 = document.getElementById('previewDescription').innerText || document.getElementById('previewDescription').textContent;

     // I want to post text1,2,3 along with sent to another page where sent get received

      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
          document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
        xmlhttp.open(form.method, form.action, true);
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

      xmlhttp.send('sent=' + sent + 'text1=' + text1 + 'text2=' + text2 + 'text3=' + text3);
    }
```

Data is coming from form having:

```
    <form>
     <input type="text" id="text" name="sent" contenteditable="true"  style=" text-align: left; height: 30px; width:512px; " placeholder="Enter URL ..."/></input>
     <div id="d1" height="40" width="60" name="sent2"  style=" border:1px solid black; z-index: 1; left: 950px; top:80px; position: absolute; margin-top: 0px" placeholder="Preview title" >
             </div>
             <div id="d2" height="40"  style="border:1px solid black; z-index: 1; left: 950px; top:100px; position: absolute; margin-top: 0px; min-width:60; overflow:auto" placeholder="Preview Url">
             </div>
             <div id="d3" height="80"  border="1" style="border:1px solid black; z-index: 1; left: 950px; top:140px; position: absolute; margin-top: 0px" placeholder="Preview Desciption">
             </div>
//Some other content
</form>
```

I also tried to get the values of  content on form submit event using this:

```
 var sent2 = form.elements['sent2'].value; //sent2 name of <div id="d1">
```

But no luck

Comment: Are you interested in jQuery or just pure JavaScript?  It appears to be pure JavaScript.

Comment: @abc123: pure JS, why you asking that here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your key/value string is missing the `&` character that separates the variables. You should also run them through [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) so that special characters are URL encoded and won't break the format.

```
sent = encodeURIComponent(sent);
text1 = encodeURIComponent(text1);
text2 = encodeURIComponent(text2);
text3 = encodeURIComponent(text3);

xmlhttp.send('sent=' + sent + '&text1=' + text1 + '&text2=' + text2 + '&text3=' + text3);
//                             ^ here              ^ here              ^ here
```

Comment: thanks, means after geting my variables `text1,2,3` at the end before sending them I should `encodeURIComponent` right?

Comment: yes, it doesn't really matter where you do the `encodeURIComponent()`, as long as you do it at some point. I just added it there for the sake of readability. I could have added around each variable in the `send()` line but it's less readable.